# How to copy local file to Azure storage (V2)

Tags: azure, storage, account

I would like to automate the process of copying a number of files from an on-premise server to an Azure Resource Manager Storage Account.  I have done this with classic storage accounts, and there are many articles available for doing this task with the classic storage accounts, but all I can find for the V2 storage accounts is cmdlets and examples that deal with copying from one Azure storage account to another.  Is it possible to do this, and if so, what cmdlet should I be using?

Comment: For this kind of actions, classic storage account and ARM deployed storage account are exactly the same.

Comment: Per Gaurav's example below, I see what you are saying, but I disagree that they are exactly the same due to the differences he pointed out.  Following a an example like this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-powershell-guide-full/
Will not work with a V2 storage account because it fails earlier in the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as managing data in a storage account is concerned (like uploading file), the process is the same for both V1 & V2 Storage accounts. Difference is how these storage accounts are managed (like fetching keys, regenerating keys etc.).

The Cmdlet that you would want to use for uploading a file is `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent`. You would first create a `AzureStorageContext` using your storage account's name and key and then upload a file using this Cmdlet.

From the Cmdlet help:

```
Get-Help Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Full

NAME
    Set-AzureStorageBlobContent

SYNOPSIS
    Upload local file to Azure Storage blob.

SYNTAX
    Set-AzureStorageBlobContent [-File] <String> [-Container] <String> [-Blob <String>] [-BlobType <String>]
    [-Properties <Hashtable>] [-Metadata <Hashtable>] [-Force [<SwitchParameter>]] [-Context <AzureStorageContext>]
    [-ServerTimeoutPerRequest <Nullable`1[Int32]>] [-ClientTimeoutPerRequest <Nullable`1[Int32]>]
    [-ConcurrentTaskCount <Nullable`1[Int32]>] [-InformationAction <ActionPreference>] [-InformationVariable <String>]
    [<CommonParameters>]
```

and here's a sample code snippet:

```
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "account-name" -StorageAccountKey "account-key"
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File "file-path" -Container "container-name" -Blob "blob-name" -Context $ctx
```